# What's the big appeal to Majestic Wilderlands?

Tags: dungeons-and-dragons, campaign-settings, osr

I've been seeing a lot about this setting lately, and although I've looked over some of the material, I don't feel like I "get" it.  That is by no means a criticism--I'm pretty interested, but it would help me a lot if someone could summarize what the setting is "about," or how it compares to other settings on a broad level.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It is a D&D style fantasy setting where the adventure results from the conflict arising from the clash of culture, religion, and society.

The book itself is meant to do two things, first it is a collection of my house rules for Swords & Wizardry and all editions based on the original 1974 roleplaying game. second it is an overview of the Majestic Wilderlands. My version of Judges Guild's Wilderlands of High Fantasy. It is a campaign that has been continuously run since 1980 using a variety of fantasy RPGs notably; AD&D 1st, Fantasy Hero, GURPS Fantasy, D&D 3.X, D&D 4.0, Harnmaster, and now Swords & Wizardry. Despite the rules changes I never strayed far the bag of stuff that makes up AD&D so hence was not hard to write it up for Swords & Wizardry.

If you look at the classes I have written about the majority arises from the consequences of my setting. Since my assumptions are similar to most D&D like settings people find them useful outside of the Majestic Wilderlands. The same for the other material in the book.

One thing I don't do is try to FIX Swords & Wizardry and other older editions. The Majestic Wilderlands is IMPLEMENTING Swords & Wizardry for my setting. I stress this because for the majority of my market the point is to play older editions of D&D or one of the retro-clones. They don't want the game "fixed". It is a subtle but important distinction for my market.

These are my goals and thoughts I used for writing the Majestic Wilderlands. Obviously I like the attention to my product, but I hope my reply help people think about how they can contribute or publish for their favorite game.

Comment: Thanks!  I actually didn't realize that it was your setting.  You've definitely sold me (although only in the figurative sense until I get some funds available for gaming purchases) :-)

Comment: Always glad to be of service :). If you buy the PDF get it off of RPGNow as there are extras I can provide there that Lulu doesn't give me the ability to upload. And there some stuff on my website http://www.batintheattic.com that may prove useful.